# Is the function a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been given the function $$ f(x) = -8x - 9  $$

I know that in order to prove this, I need make sure it satisfies the f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) rule as well as the scalar rule. But i'm not exactly sure what lies in between. What is f(x+y) here, in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x+y)$ is the following : in the expression $-8x-9$, *replace* "x" with "x+y". That makes the expression into $f(x+y) = -8(x+y)-9$.

Now, you are asked if this is a linear transformation. Well, for that you have to check if $f(x)+f(y) = f(x+y)$. To find $f(y)$, *replace* "x" with "y". That gives you $-8y-9$.

Now, you have well-meaning expressions on both sides. On side is $-8x-9 + (-8y-9)$. The other side is $-8(x+y)-9$.

Now, simplify using ordinary rules, and you will see that $-8x-8y-18 \neq -8(x+y)-9$, so the function is not a linear transformation as additivity is not satisfied.

Scalar multiplication need not be checked once you have verified the above, but let's go through it anyway. So let's take $f(cx)$, where we just *replace* "x" with "cx". Now, we see that the expression is $-8cx-9$. On the other side, $cf(x) = -8xc-9c$. Obviously, since $-8xc-9 \neq -8xc-9c$, the function does not even satisfy scalar multiplication law.

So this function is clearly not a linear transformation.

As a matter of fact, a *necessary* condition for a linear transformation is that it must give $f(0)=0$. Here though, $f(0)= -8*0-9 = -9$, so we directly see that $f$ is not linear from here itself.

Comment: Wow. Made so simple. Thank you so so much.

Comment: You are welcome. It is my job to make topics easy to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x+y)=-8(x+y)-9$

Is this equal to $f(x)+f(y)=-8x-9-8y-9$?

Try with $x=y=0$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I always do when asked if a mapping $f:V \to U$ between vector spaces $V$ and $U$ is linear, is trying if $f(0) = 0$. If $f$ is linear
$$f(0) = f(0 + 0 ) = f(0) + f(0).$$
Subtracting both sides by $f(0)$ yields $f(0) = 0$.

Note that $f(0) = 0$ is not enough to guarantee that $f$ is linear (e.g. $f(x) = x^2$). However, if $f(0) \neq 0$, $f$ cannot be linear. This is often a quick thing to try and sometimes (e.g. in your case) proves that $f$ is not linear.